# installing plugins like ESLint and Babel

Tags: node.js, terminal, babeljs, eslint, npm-live-server

Having some issues. I have installed Node + NPM, and finally got Live-server to work. I am trying to install babel and ESLint with terminal. But the commands are not found when I try to check the versions.

user-MBP:~ user$ which live-server
/usr/local/bin/live-server
user-MBP:~ user$ which babel
user-MBP:~ user$ which eslint

do i need to install babel and eslint in the same /usr/local/bin/?

Answer (score 0):

Babel and ESLint are NPM packages, meaning you install them with the NPM package manager. ESLint is straight forward, type:

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

You may be able to install Babel the same way:

```
npm install babel
```

However Babel is a little more involved and might require some configuration, I recommend finding an article to walk you through it. This one looks reasonable:
http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial/setup-babel/